# When using a PIL image object with reportlab drawImage gives

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I am trying to insert a PIL image object into a pdf using  reportlab drawImage method.

```
 im=Image.open('back_ground.png')
 side_im=im.crop((2,2,277,819))
 c=canvas.Canvas('report.pdf')
 c.drawImage(side_im,200,700)
```

And I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for an update since StringIO has been deprecated in Python3. import io instead of StringIO and use io.BytesIO()

```
import io
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader

im=Image.open('back_ground.png')
side_im=im.crop((2,2,277,819))
c=canvas.Canvas('report.pdf')

#c.drawImage(side_im,200,700)
side_im_data = io.BytesIO()
side_im.save(side_im_data, format='png')
side_im_data.seek(0)
side_out = ImageReader(side_im_data)
c.drawImage(side_out,200,700)
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
import StringIO
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader

im=Image.open('back_ground.png')
side_im=im.crop((2,2,277,819))
c=canvas.Canvas('report.pdf')

#c.drawImage(side_im,200,700)
side_im_data = StringIO.StringIO()
side_im.save(side_im_data, format='png')
side_im_data.seek(0)
side_out = ImageReader(side_im_data)
c.drawImage(side_out,200,700)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for around 3 months.   After upgrading python to 3.8, reportlab to 3.5.42, Pillow to 7.0.0, it started working again on amazon ec2 instance.   previously it was crashing the Django gunicorn server causing a 502 error.